# What is the best way to separate javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two javascript files that come in conflict with each other. One is to open modals and uses links like `<a href="#modal" data-toggle="modal">open modal</a>`, and would then open the modal with `id="modal"`. But the other script is for smooth scroll and it removes the anchor from the url `(I'd like to keep that part!)` but after adding the smooth scroll script, the modals don't work. any ideas how I can fix it?

modal.js:

```
$(".modal-wide").on("show.modal", function() {

  var height = $(window).height() - 200;
  $(this).find(".modal-body").css("max-height", height);
});
$('a[data-toggle="modal"]').bind('click',function(){
  $('.modal').modal('hide');
});
```

scroll.js:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

scroll.js source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Comment: Is it a bootstrap modal? version 3?

Comment: @amenadiel I honestly don't know where I got the modal code from, but I belive it is from bootstrap 3.0 yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding your specific href tags to the not selector the the smooth scroll function.

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"]):not([href="#modal"])').click(function()
```

Here is a fiddle showing the smoothscroll only works for the smooth scroll div which should preserve your modal functionality.

https://jsfiddle.net/bryangators/wjgu1vL9/

Comment: hmm this is nice, but the `href="#modal"` would open a modal that had the id of `modal`. so with this code I would have to add every modal id to the `:not` part.

Can it be done with `data-toggle="modal"` instead?

Comment: ooh nvm. was able to test it my self and the code works now with `$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"]):not([data-toggle="modal"])').click(function() { `. thanks for your help :)